# Ember can't iterate over model with array property

Tags: arrays, ember.js, components, ember-data

I have a model, `values.js`:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    values: [
        { name: "Quality", isChecked: DS.attr('bool') },
        { name: "Inspiration", isChecked: DS.attr('bool') },
        { name: "Creativity", isChecked: DS.attr('bool') },
        { name: "Commitment", isChecked: DS.attr('bool') },
        { name: "Honour", isChecked: DS.attr('bool') }
    ]
});
```

And in the route `passport-values.js` I am creating a values model:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model () {
        return this.store.createRecord('values');
    }
});
```

I have a component, `passport-basic.hbs`:

```
<h2>{{title}}</h2>
<p>{{content}}</p>
<form>
    <fieldset class="checkboxes">
        {{#each model as |value index|}}
            <label>{{input type="checkbox" onchange=(action "change") checked=value.isChecked name="value.name"}}{{value.name}}</label>
        {{/each}}
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Which I am using from my template, `passport-values.hbs`, and passing my model with:

```
{{passport-basic title="" content="" model=values}}
```

In the component I am trying to iterate over all the values within the array in the model to display a label with the name and checkbox that represents whether the isChecked option is true/false for each value. I have experimented with ideas from a lot of other sources, but i can't seem to make this work.

Thanks for the help, I'm still very new to Ember.js and I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the examples in The Guides for [Defining Models](https://guides.emberjs.com/current/models/defining-models/) and [Finding Records](https://guides.emberjs.com/current/models/finding-records/) in order to iterate over a collection in the way you've described, and take advantage of Ember's built in ways to persist records.

Your value model should look like this:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  quality: DS.attr('boolean'),
  inspiration: DS.attr('boolean'),
  honor: DS.attr('boolean'),
  creativity: DS.attr('boolean'),
  commitment: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

Then in your route, do

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('value');
  }
});
```

Your model hook will return a collection of values that you can pass to a component just how you described:

```
{{passport-basic title="" content="" model=values}}
```

and you can use the value attributes in your templates like this:

```
{{#each model as |value|}}
  <p>{{value.honor}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm still learning about Ember.js so these things will come in time. :)

Comment: Good luck and welcome to Ember :D It all definitely gets easier as you go.

Answer (score 0):

Models are not meant to contain data, they define attributes which turn a JSON payload into a record.

> Attributes are used when turning the JSON payload returned from your server into a record, and when serializing a record to save back to the server after it has been modified. https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.15.0/models/defining-models/#toc_defining-attributes

If you do not need to persist your data or you are just testing a template. You can define an array and pass it in as a model on your route.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    values: [
      { name: "Quality", isChecked: false },
      { name: "Inspiration", isChecked: false },
      { name: "Creativity", isChecked: false },
      { name: "Commitment", isChecked: false },
      { name: "Honour", isChecked: false }
    ],
    model () {
      return this.get('values');
    }
});
```

Edit: and as a correction, technically you can create records this way without a database you just can't save it.

The correct syntax would be.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  quality: DS.attr('boolean'),
  inspiration: DS.attr('boolean'),
  honor: DS.attr('boolean'),
  creativity: DS.attr('boolean'),
  commitment: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

Comment: Ok, so how would I do this if I need to persist the data? I'm currently looking at creating an Ember object in the route?

Comment: I'd say that's beyond the scope of this question. But basically you'll need to look into how to save data to a database and serve it up as JSON. Ember can persist the data temporarily but can't save it long term without some sort of server side integration. @Oli